# Single knock sound when stepping on gas

Tags: mazda-3

My mazda 3, AT makes a slight knocking sound when I suddenly press the accelerator pedal, and the engine is at low RPM and the gear is high.

e.g. 1500rpm, 4th gear, at 40 km/h

ATF Oil was changed already a few months ago.

Where could the sound be coming from?

Comment: Do you get the knock if you shift from drive to reverse and  then drive again?

Comment: Where exactly does the sound emanate from? Does it sound like an engine noise or does it reverberate through the cab as though the noise is coming from the body of the car? Also, if you have your gear selector in 4th gear, with an AT it doesn't mean the tranny is in 4th gear. I take it if you step on the gas it is not down shifting?

Comment: Mikes: sometimes it knocks when I engage the reverse when I'm parking. The shift stick vibrates.

Comment: Paulster: it seems to come from the transmission. I can feel like something blocking or stopping the turning motion of the wheels. Transmission is in manual mode (steptronic)

Comment: In the future, please put an "at symbol" (@) in front of the person's name (ie: @mikes ) so we'll get notification :D It's all a learning curve!

Comment: I jacked up both front wheels. When I turn the wheels manually with my hand it makes clacking noise. Is it normal? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUP4Num-Mrs

Comment: Usually when you get clicking sounds like you are showing in the video, it is coming from the constant velocity (CV) joint. You may hear it more prevalent if you turn the wheel to the right or left and then turn the wheel. If this does not change the noise, it would be internal to your transmission.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.Oh dear, is it safe to drive my car?

Comment: Is it inner or outer cv joint? I will try turning the wheels left and right tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

My mechanic checked today. It was the lock bolt that was loose. he tightened it and the knocking sound went away.

http://www.thaimazda3.com/svmanual/esicont/en/srvc/html/B3E031325500W03.html

That's item no 2 in the link above.

I shudder to think what would have happened if it came loose. Wouldn't that make the car spin?

Comment: I can't see it in the picture but typically there is a locking pin that goes through that bolt.

Comment: Considering the components which have to be removed to get a CV axle out, there would be a considerable amount of noise before anything catastrophic happened. Long term it could accelerate the failure of the CV joint and if that joint failed then you would have a steel bar whipping around under your car.